# Read UTF-8 Lines of Text and Write them to File

Tags: php

I fetch lines of UTF-8 text from a page then dump into a file. The text in the original page appears fine. However, the text in the output file appears scrambled!

**My attempt:**

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$pageContent = file_get_contents("page.html");
//Here: use regex to grab the title ...
$stringData = $title."\n";
fwrite($fh, utf8_encode($stringData));
fclose($fh);
```

Before writing anything to the file. I saved the file as UTF-8 and i also saved it as Unicode, i still get scrambled text as:

> ÊãäíÇÊí ááÌãíÚ

I'm not using PHP5

**Any help will be appreciated...**

Comment: `I'm not using PHP5` - is there nothing you can do about this? PHP4 is desperately out of date and does not support many security features. I know it is not always possible to upgrade (I have this perpetual problem myself with one specific platform) but if you can upgrade, you absolutely must...

Comment: Not using PHP5 temporarily...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't use `utf8_encode`!**

Sorry for the shouting, it's just misused way too often.
Your text is already in UTF-8.* You do not need to encode it to UTF-8 again.
`utf8_encode` *converts* Latin1 encoded text to UTF-8. Your text is not Latin1 encoded. That's why it screws up. Just read and write the text, done. No encoding conversion or re-encoding necessary.

<sub>* Assuming `page.html` *is* encoded in UTF-8. From what you're saying, it seems to be.</sub>

Comment: I guess you should add that the scrambled characters the OP is seeing are probably the result of *viewing* the utf8 output in a non-utf8 viewer (like maybe the command line). [P.S. You are totally right about my post, I had a brainfart; post deleted]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are double encoding.  If you read the [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) documentation you'll see that it is designed to encode ISO-8859-1 strings into UTF-8.  If you've already got a UTF-8 string you should not run this function on it; otherwise it will interpret it as ISO-8859-1 and do incorrect encoding.